# How do I enable the gruvbox airline after installing gruvbox with Vundle?

Tags: colorscheme

If I understood it correctly gruvbox has it's own airline and you don't need vim-airline installed. I followed the easy install with Vundle but for some reason the airline just doesn't load. I'm using Konsole as a terminal. Thank you.

Comment: No, Gruvbox comes with an airline theme that can be applied to airline.

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble. A bit new to this and realized that you still have to install airline.

Comment: correct. If you want to use the gruvbox **theme** with vim-airline, you have to install the gruvbox colorscheme plugin in addition to vim-airline.

Comment: @turtlewin want to add that as an answer?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I can't seem to add an answer myself or make the comment an accepted answer. God it feels good to be a newbie, everything amazes me.

Comment: Comments can't be answers. I'll add the answer then, since it was my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gruvbox is a colorscheme, and comes packaged with an airline theme as can be seen by the inclusion of an [autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/blob/master/autoload/airline/themes/gruvbox.vim) file.

Gruvbox itself does not come with airline, but it supports it.

To use airline, you will need to install it; then, you may `let g:airline_theme = 'gruvbox'` in your vimrc.